# Convert node module's exported functions' into JSON objects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, user-interface, architecture, modularity

it is my first question so I hope I'll write it well, any suggestion is well accepted. This is a design question.

I'm using the create-electron-app-typescript boilerplate. I use uniforms & JSON schemas for user input, and I'm new to all of these languages/tools.

I'm designing a tool that aims to create a simple, general graphical interface for modules that can expose (export) certain functionalities.
e.g.:

```
module.exports = { 
   function sendMoney(account?, amount),
   function foo(something)
}
```

I wish I could translate each function in a schema like this:

```
{
"title": "sendMoney",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "account": { 
          "type":"string" 
     },
    "amount": {
          "type":"int"
     }
 },
"required": ["amount"]
}
```

in order to easily translate it instantly into a form as I do now using Uniforms/React.
The **goal** is to let the user implicitly create a high level "script" which is the ordered and sequential execution of these functions, that will be interpreted in a second moment.

[EDITED]

Comment: I think your question is _way_ too broad, this is more as you said a design question, nothing wrong with that, but for now it's too vague. I would advise you to try building something, and then, if you encounter problems ask for help.

Comment: @geauser thanks for the advice. I'll reformulate to make question more specific for the actual obstacle.